# How can I say “stout”, “lager”, “saison”, and “trappist” in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for different beer types in Esperanto.

I have looked in the Lernu Vortaro, Reta Vortaro, Wiktionary and Wikipedia, but I only found a few, like *ale* which is *elo* and *IPA* which is *hinda hela elo*.

Does anybody know how to say any of the following?

- stout
- lager
- saison
- trappist

Comment: Some relevant links:
[trappist & saison](http://www.esperanto.be/fel/mon/007144.html),
[stout & lager](http://lernu.net/eo/forumo/temo/8534).

Comment: +1 for asking about the translation of trappist ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These words are all internationalisms, so you only have to decide whether to respell them (to make them easier to say) or leave them (to make them easier to recognize in reading).

- *staŭto* or stout-*biero* or *fortportero*
- *lagero* or *lagerbiero*
- *saisono* or *sezonbiero*
- *trapista biero* or *trapistbiero*

If it's obvious in context that you're talking about beer then you don't have to add *biero* all the time, e.g. *Koncerne la trinkaĵojn, mi elektis staŭton kaj mia amiko elektis trapistan.*

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "internationalism"?

Comment: *Vortoj fremdaj* (Rule 15), not in the *Universala Vortaro*, which many diverse languages have taken from one source, most likely to be recognised in a form close to the original.